# Django error_messages not working in my model but works in my view?

Tags: python, django

So i'm simply trying to pass out my own custom error which works in my view here below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from TasksManager.models import Supervisor, Developer
from django import forms

class someView(forms.Form):
    error_name = {'required':'You must type a name !','invalid':'Wrong format.'}
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=30, error_messages=error_name)
```

but when i try to do it in a model it just ignores the custom error_message i'm passing through to it and uses djangos built in error_message code below:

```
from django.db import models

class someModel(models.Model):
    error_name = {'required':'You must type a name !','invalid':'Wrong format.'}
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name", error_messages=error_name)
```

What could i do to make this work in my model(how do i make my 2nd block of code work)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the available error types are null, blank, invalid, invalid_choice, unique, and unique_for_date. There is no 'required' error type.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#error-messages